# WebRTC security options with XSockets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, webrtc, xsockets.net

If I follow the example outlined on this page "http://xsockets.net/docs/installing-xsocketsnet" and install the controller as a self hosted application on a different server from the web server hosting the website that would communicate with the XSocket controller, how can I make sure that only authenticated users from my website can access the XSocket controller.

I am new to XSockets architecture and this is puzzling me.  It seems like I would need to pass some login credentials to the Controller when this line of code is called `peerBroker = new XSockets.WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:4502/CustomBroker");` in JavaScript.  I have not found any documentation outlining how to get this information securely to the Controller.  As a background, the website side is running MVC5.

The main point of confusion is that the broker is on a different server as the mvc5 application that will access the broker.  I am trying to make sure that the broker only allows users currently logged into the system access to the broker.

Comment: What kind of information do you have about the user? FormAuth ticket? Token of some kind?

Comment: you could only create the broker and launch it if they are authenticated. There are many ways to check authentication in asp.net

Comment: I have FormsAuth ticket and I have their username/password.  If the controller(broker) is self hosted on a different server, would that eliminate FormsAuth as an option?  I am trying to force authentication on the broker side, so this seems to be outside of normal asp.net authentication, as I want to eliminate the possibility of anyone trying to access the broker without being logged into the website.  I already have authentication on the mvc side; I just want it on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

To share the auth ticket between servers is actually not that hard.

1. See to it that you have the same machine key in both configs.

   ```
   //Machine key in web
   <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" validationKey="validation-key-here" decryptionKey="decryption-key-here" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

   //Machine key in app-server
   <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" validationKey="same-as-on-webserver" decryptionKey="same-as-on-webserver" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

   //Do note that compabilityMode will be different between 4.5 and other .NET versions see [MSDN][1]
   ```
2. When you login with forms-auth you will get a cookie like

   ```
   .ASPXAUTH=DFE811295BABA98CFE94040...
   ```
3. To get that cookie in XSockets.NET just do like this

   ```
   public class MyController : XSocketController
   {
       public MyController()
       {            
           this.OnOpen += MyController_OnClientConnect;
       }

       void MyController_OnClientConnect(object sender, XSockets.Core.Common.Socket.Event.Arguments.OnClientConnectArgs e)
       {
           var ticket = GetFormsAuthenticationTicket();
           //Validate ticket & maybe extract user info as shown below...
           //If not valid just call this.Close();
       }
   }
   ```
4. It is not nessesary, but as you see you can pass along custom client information. I do so by using a custom pricncipal

   ```
   public class CustomPrincipal
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string[] Roles { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. In that case you can extract user info from the ticket with

   ```
   var userinfo = this.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<CustomPrincipal>(ticket.UserData);
   ```

Note: Read http://xsockets.net/docs/security where you will see that you can also use the Authorize attribute and also use the OnAuthorization method (override)

EDIT: To be able to access the cookies on the xsockets server you will have to connect to the same origin as the cookie was set on. For example: If you connect to localhost (web) you will have to use ws://localhost:port to be able to access to the cookie.